# how to get Temporary path of the uploaded file in the IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

i want to get the full path of the uploaded file in the IIS Server without saving the file in the disk by calling File.SaveAs() method. why i want to do this?. Once i have the full path of the file without saving it in the disk i want to upload this file in azure blob container.

I have successfully uploaded the file in azure blob container after saving the file in the disk but i don't want to first save and then delete the file from disk after uploading the file to azure blob container.

Comment: How could you possibly get the path of a file which has not been saved yet.

Comment: You need to access the stream of the file being uploaded and be pushing the stream as its being read to azure. Can you post whatever you have at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files posted to the server are stored in streams, not in temporary directories. Assuming your object is of type HttpPostedFileBase, you would need to access the InputStream property and read the bytes into your Azure Blob.

Comment: Yeah my object is of type httpPostedFileBase. I will look into this. Thanks